# Computing HOG features

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have one problem in the second step which is to accumulate weighted votes for gradient orientation over spatial cells.

Assuming the cell is `8*8`. Let me use two matrix `GO[8][8]([1 9])`, `GM[8][8]` to represent the gradient orientation and gradient magnitude respectively.
The gradient orientation ranges from `0 - 180` and there are `9` orientation bins.

According to my understanding of HOG, for every pixel in a cell, adding its gradient magnitude to its corresponding orientation bin. In this way, we can have the histogram for every cell.

But there is one sentence thats confusing me.

> "*To reduce aliasing, votes(gradient magnitude) are interpolated
>   trilinearly between the neighbouring bin centers in both orientation
>   and position.*"<sup>1</sup>

Why interpolated? How to interpolate? Can someone explains more detailed? No reducing aliasing.

Thanks in advance.

---

<sup>1</sup> This sentence is in Navneet Dalal's PHD thesis, p38, line 4.

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417531/hog-what-is-done-in-the-contrast-normalization-step/32465249#32465249

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interpolation is a standard technique for computing histograms.  The idea here is that each value is not simply placed into one bin, but is distributed between two neighboring bins (assuming a 1d histogram), based on how far away it is from the center of the original bin.

The purpose of this is to deal with situations when a small error in your measurement can cause a value to be placed into a different bin.  This is a very good thing to do for any type of histogram, not just for HOGs, assuming you have the CPU cycles.

There is also bi-linear and tri-linear interpolation for 2d and 3d histograms, where each value is distributed between 4 and 8 neighboring bins respectively.